Postgres copy to STDOUT hangs indefinetly
I have a script that runs COPY on postgres to STDOUT. This stream is consumed by nodejs into a readable. This readable is passed to pipeline which writes to a csv file locally. I am using nodePG and nodePG-copy-stream to handle creating the postgres client and copy stream. Lastly, I execute my script with bun. I attached my example read/write code below.
const saveCopyStreamToFile = async (
  pgPool: pg.Pool,
  copyQuery: string,
  fileName: string
) => {
  console.log(fileName);
  const client = await pgPool.connect();
  const readable = client.query(copyTo(copyQuery));

  const writeable = createWriteStream(`${os.homedir()}/cms/${fileName}`, {
    highWaterMark: 64 * 1024
  });

  try {
    await pipeline(readable, writeable);
  } finally {
    client.release();
  }
};

The Issue: On a certain table, the copy stream hangs indefinetly. I attached event listeners and the read stream never sends a close event. It does recieve data events and chunks. When I inspect the file, I can see the data begins to break randomly when writing a row in the csv. For example, XYZ utilizes a configuH djid is a cell in the csv where the break begins. Interestingly, a different package postgresjs works fine on this table, but runs into the same issue on a different table. Lastly, I inspected the pg_stat_activity table and can see the process in there stuck in the idle state.
Expected: I can write the postgres copy stream to a csv file locally.
NodePg: https://node-postgres.com/
PostgresJs: https://github.com/porsager/postgres

From the example here pg-copy-streams there seems to be an await pool.end() that you do not have.

I actually do include the pool.end() in the function that calls the one I supplied here. I can see by the events that the stream never closes, not the client. There are multiple calls of saveCopyStreamToFile for a number of tables. The issue is one of the tables hangs indefinitely when copying/saving the file.

Try using COPY TO STDOUT from psql and see if it hangs in the same way.

@LaurenzAlbe Tried that out with /COPY via PSQL and it worked totally fine! Same table and everything. I was hoping to use a library so we didn't have to open connections for every single request. But I may be SOL.

So you can rule out the database as cause of your problem. That will make debugging easier.
